# Track user data and display it in a graph [Android]

Tags: android

I'd like to ask for your help regarding my Android project. I'm planning to track user's data like BMI, and display it in a bar graph. Please give me some help how to implement, what APIs could I use and if you have any experiences developing an app like this, kindly give me some details how to get started.

Thanks.

Comment: Would the "user data" be manually entered by the user?

Comment: The user data are entered by the user then my app will calculate it's BMI. After the calculation, the result will be stored in the DB and if the user wants to view her results, it would be displayed in a bar graph for comparison, if ever she does it weekly, monthly or so.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user data in a sqlite3 or a flat file-based database, where you read the values into an array when you want to graph them:

At first you should query all the wanted data from the db, and iterate the cursor to put them into a array, or dataset, or whatever the graphing library wants.

(I'm in kind of a hurry now, so I will not go into details of a graphing tool, but maybe later. Most of the packages seem to have a good example for XY- or line-graphs, but seems that a bar-graph example would require more searching)

Basically you would a graph-view into a layout, find the view by id, and then set the data of the graph to the one you queried from the db.

By quick searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/1856369). I think most of the graphing libraries there would have an ability to create a bar graph.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a sqlite DB. Since the data to be stored is in run time. I'd like to ask you more details on how to display the data from DB into bar graph? Can you give me some piece of code to get started? THanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not brave enough to give some code, which I haven't tested, as there are no guarantees that it would work. It seems that the part requiring most work is the graphing API.